# Laptop CPU fan replacement

Tags: laptop, cooling

Recently my MSI GE60 2PL cpu fan started rattling and making weird noises as if its blades were touching something.
I opened the laptop and removed dust from fan (i removed the fan too to check if something was stuck in it) after some more testing and research I came to the conclusion that the fan "died".
So i ask you this : what brands do you suggest for replacement ? Knowing that my warranty has expired and that sending my laptop to some MSI support center (?) is out of the question.
PS : I did find some replacements in aliexpress but i'm just not sure which brand to buy.
Thanks

Comment: You may want to call up MSI Support to see if you can buy a single fan from them. That way it is guaranteed to work with your laptop.

Comment: @Cfinley My problem isn't whether the fan is going to work with the my laptop or not but rather which brand should I get (I've found several) since I don't think they (MSI) can ship to my country (Morocco). Plus, I've found out that the MSI GE60 series has always had a problem with CPU fans so I'm rather reluctant to buying a new one from MSI. Thanks

Comment: @RedanN laptop fans aren't usually sold on a by-part basis unlike desktop fans. You're probably not going to find a specific fan just for you. That's why Cfinley recommended you talk to MSI b/c they are most likely to have your specific laptop fan.

Comment: I have the same issue on the same computer, just the 2PE model. I bought new fans and changed them but they dont start :( any idea what to do?

Answer (score -1):

Please check [here](https://www.ekl-ag.de/en/products/it-solutions?gclid=Cj0KEQjwuOHHBRDmvsHs8PukyIQBEiQAlEMW0CUmE6K-EuZnO067tIG0JPJAMEMw2HZvRjD29fg3LYoaAmZW8P8HAQ) I had some problem like this and this website solve my problem.
I hope this could help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in the website you gave they had only desktop cooling solution whereas in my case it's a laptop.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Laptop-Replacement-Toshiba-Satellite-purchase/dp/B00CMO72J4

Comment: While this link *may* answer the question (I can't tell), it would be better to quote the relevant parts of the linked page here, and leave the link for reference. Unquoted links are liable to become dead links, and then this answer becomes useless.